# How to disable Jhipter terminal notifier

Tags: macos, terminal, jhipster

Is it possible to disable JHipster terminal notifier? It's so useless and spammy
[image]

Comment: Did you look at the webpack configuration ?

Comment: @Ckram inside webpack.dev.js file there was WebpackNotifierPlugin, just removed and works nice, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ckram suggested, inside `webpack/webpack.dev.js` just remove `WebpackNotifierPlugin` and all its usages to remove all notifications